# Galaxy s2 stuck in flight mode

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-2, apk, locked-out

I am attempting to unlock my old galaxy s2 without needing to reset it. My original plan was to get the pin wrong 5 times, then unlock using google account. However, when I inserted the sim card I turned flight mode on to make the phone reset its network and use the sim card. it got stuck there. It would not let me press the flight mode button again, so I rebooted it.

Now the device says flight mode is disabled in the power menu, but displays the flight symbol in the notification bar.

There are two possible ways I can think of solving this. Firstly, if anyone could please suggest any way of fixing the flight mode problem I am having.

The second solution is I have the apk of screen lock bypass pro on my pc, but I haven't found a way of installing it on my phone from my pc as the phone is not connected to the internet and apowersoft's phone manager didn't actually install it.